# Dependabot ignoring default branch and opening some PR's against master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, dependabot

We have the following dependabot.yml config:-

```
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "bundler"
    directory: "/app"
    target-branch: "develop"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
```

Around 60% of the PRs that dependabot opens however, are against our master branch.  When I try changing the base branch to develop and re-running dependabot rebase or recreate, it flips the branch back to master.

I read that dependabot sometimes opens security PRs against master, but if that's the case - what's the point in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Dependabot has 2 types of updates:

- Package version updates are configured in `dependabot.yml`.
- Security updates are configured via a repo's Security tab. Security PRs always go to `main`.

https://github.com/community/community/discussions/11710

Does this describe what you're seeing? I'm struggling too, been researching for 3 days - it seems to aggravate lots of people. I'll bet eventually security updates will be configurable in `dependabot.yml` - but I couldn't find a road map saying so :(